# Update the values of a Kendo grid column which is populated by remote data

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid which is rendered as soon as the page loads. The grid is populated by remote data.

```
 logMonitoringGrid.kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    batch: true,
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: window.$vars['webApiHost'] + "logs",
                            dataType: "json",
                        }
                    },
                    serverFiltering: false,
                    serverPaging: false,
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            id: "Id",
                            fields: {
                                Id: { type: "number" },
                                TTId: { type: "string" },
                                LUId: { type: "number" },
                                Level: { type: "string" },
                                Server: { type: "string" },
                                Thread: { type: "number" },
                                Message: { type: "string" },
                                Ip: { type: "string" },
                                RId: { type: "string" },
                                Timestamp: { type: "date" }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                columns: columnObjects
            });

var lGrid = logMonitoringGrid.data("kendoGrid");
```

There's another API which has the data of all the tenants like this (JSON)

```
{
    Id: 5196
    Name: "unittest"
    ContactEmail: "admin@unittest.com"
    Theme: "default"
    DefaultLocale: "en-US"
    IsInternal: false
}
```

I need to replace the Tenant Id of each row of the grid with their corresponding tenant names. The remote data of the grid does not send any tenant names with it. That's why I am creating a map of all the tenant ids and their names.

```
 var tenantData = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                            o9Util.setRequestHeaders(xhr);
                        },
                        url: crudUrl("tenants"),
                        dataType: "json"
                    }
                }
            });

            var myMap = new Map();

            tenantData.fetch(function () {
                var data = tenantData.data();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    myMap.set(data[i].Id, data[i].Name);
                }
            })
```

Now I'm updating the grid column like this

```
lGrid.dataSource.fetch(function () {
                var data = this.data();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    for (var [key, value] of myMap.entries()) {
                        if (parseInt(data[i].TTId) === key) {
                            data[i].set("TTId", value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
```

This approach works but takes some time to change the values of the column whenever the page loads. Moreover the page becomes unresponsive after some time. Is there any other way I can update the grid as soon as the page loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A suggest the following:

1. Make your API(tenants) call before Kendo's call. Remember to initialize the grid when this requests finishes, that means, on [DataSource's `requestEnd` event](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/events/requestend);
2. Initialize your grid;
3. In the Grid's [`dataSource.schema.parse`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/schema#schema.parse) you set the values you want. Example:

   ```
   logMonitoringGrid.kendoGrid({
       dataSource: {
           schema: {
               parse: function(data) {
                   let tenantJsonData = tenantData.data().toJSON();

                   data.forEach(item => {
                       let tenantItem = tenantJsonData.find(ti => ti.Id === item.TTId);

                       if (tenantItem) {
                           item.TTTId = tenantItem.Name;
                       }
                   });

                   return data;
               }
           }
       }
    }
   ```

I didn't tested it, but it should work.